# How do I work out what the problem is with the emacs package system?

Tags: package, package-repositories

I am trying to set up emacs (on cygwin / Win10) to handle JSON.

I started with [joshwnj/json-mode](https://github.com/joshwnj/json-mode) and was stoked to discover that emacs will now install its own dependencies from online repos. Fab stuff.

I can run `M-x package-install` but I notice it logs the message:

```
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80
Failed to download ‘gnu’ archive.
```

And when I type in `json-mode`, emacs says there's no match. Is this a connection problem? Should I see an HTTP error somewhere?

joshwnj/json-mode says I need the MELPA repository set up.

According to [this documentation for MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started) I need to identify if I'm using package.el (which looks good) and work out if the given lisp code is in place.

Is there a command I can run in emacs to tell me if this code is in place?

Trying to following on and ignoring that issue, I tried `M-x package-list-packages` and got the following error:

```
You can run the command ‘package-list-packages’ with M-x pa-l- RET
Waiting for refresh to finish...
Package refresh done
No packages to upgrade.
error in process sentinel: Error retrieving: http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/archive-contents (error connection-failed "failed with code 10060
" :host "elpa.gnu.org" :service 80)
error in process sentinel: Error retrieving: http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/archive-contents (error connection-failed "failed with code 10060
" :host "elpa.gnu.org" :service 80)
```

Is the `sentinel` process critical? Did the package refresh work?

What should I try next?

Answer (score 7):

It appears that

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 '(gnutls-algorithm-priority "normal:-vers-tls1.3"))
```

fixes the problem.

Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60638601/850781

Comment: How did you find this out?

Comment: @mtd: [`emacs-devel` mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-devel)

Comment: thanks.  FWIW, I am still seeing the reported symptom, and your fix addressing it, using emacs 27.1 (` emacs-27.1-2.fc33.x86_64`).

Comment: fwiw it fixed it for me on "GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0, Carbon Version 165 AppKit 2113) of 2021-12-11"

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to set the `package-archives` variable in your configuration file?

I have added the following lines to my configuration to get packages from elpa, marmalade, and melpa:

```
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

Comment: Although I haven't checked, I assume I already have those set by default because of the error. If I do `M-x package-refresh-contents` I get `Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80 Failed to download ‘gnu’ archive.`

Comment: The ELPA repository may be set up by default, but the MELPA (which you said that you needed) and Maramalde repositories won't be set up by default.

Comment: Looking into the issue further, are you by chance behind a firewall? That may be blocking your connection to ELPA. Furthermore, have you installed [GnuTLS](https://www.gnutls.org/)? If you are on Windows, i refer you to [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5g4jdi/having_issues_with_downloading_packages_and/dapwauk/?st=jc6ve7ak&sh=95ddbe15), and this may also [be useful](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27202/how-do-i-install-gnutls-for-emacs-25-1-on-windows).

Comment: I run emacs under cygwin and cygwin has gnutls - is that not enough?

Comment: Not sure, I don't have access to a Windows box to test it.