# package refresh hangs

Tags: package

On Emacs 26.3, Ubuntu 20.04, when I run

```
emacs -Q
```

followed by

```
(package-refresh-contents)
```

I get

```
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
```

So the package refresh just hangs. I tried to switch from https to http, but no luck.

Comment: FWIW there was a [bug](https://gnu.emacs.bug.narkive.com/d7AZ6sQP/bug-17879-24-3-92-package-refresh-contents-hangs-at-contacting-host-melpa-milbox-net-80) about this (closed as unfixed). I still have the issue (Emacs hangs, not only stuck at "Contacting host: ...") with GNU Emacs 26.1

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 '(gnutls-algorithm-priority "normal:-vers-tls1.3"))
```

Found by @sds (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/56067/21569) and the [emacs-devel mailing list](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=36725#8) (Cf. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/56067/795 ).

Supposedly the underlying issue was fixed in emacs 26.3, but I still see it in emacs 27.1[^1].

[^1]: exact versions

```
( cat /etc/fedora-release ; uname -a ; rpm -q emacs) | sed -e "s/$(hostname)/XXX/"
Fedora release 33 (Thirty Three)
Linux XXX 5.10.12-200.fc33.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 1 02:40:52 UTC 2021 x86_64 
x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
emacs-27.1-2.fc33.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue with the *MELPA stable* repository (GNU Emacs 26.1 on Debian 10.6), I've been able to workaround this with :

```
(package-initialize)
(setq package-check-signature nil)
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives '(
    ("melpa-stable" . "http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/stable.melpa.org/packages/")
    )
)
```

with some limitations / remarks :

- List of MELPA mirrors : https://github.com/melpa/melpa#mirrors
- I've not been able to make this work on HTTPS
- the order of directives *looks* important (read [this](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4453#issuecomment-417957622) and [this](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4453#issuecomment-470951804))

Comment: I suggest you to look into fixing HTTPS. It will affect far more than just fetching packages. The package signature part isn't required if you only use MELPA.