# How do I bind C-x p to the project.el project-prefix-map?

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys, project

Following the advice of Mastering Emacs I'm trying to use the `project.el` package. My problem is that `C-x p` isn't bound to the prefix keymap and I can't figure out how to bind it correctly.

I'm pretty sure I'm trying to get this part of the package to load: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/project.el#L618

I've tried this:

```
(use-package project
  :bind-keymap ("C-x p" . project-prefix-map))
```

but I get a `Wrong type argument: sequencep`

I've tried `bind-key` but I don't know what to put in for the `COMMAND` argument so I tried this:

```
(bind-key "C-x p" project-prefix-map)
```

which is also wrong.

I'm running Emacs on MacOS. The Emacs version is GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0, NS appkit-1894.60 Version 10.15.7 (Build 19H15)) installed using macports.

Comment: All you have to do is uncomment [line 639](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/project.el#L639), the line that reads `;;;###autoload (define-key ctl-x-map "p" project-prefix-map)`: just get rid of the three semicolons and then reload `project.el`.

Comment: I'm not sure editing a core library is the way to go but I can copy the code and make the map work that way.

Comment: You can just add the `(define-key ctl-x-map "p" project-prefix-map)` to your init file anywhere *after* you `(require 'project)` instead of changing the file.

Comment: Cool, I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: To close the loop adding the key-map directly in the init file fixed the problem. I also found that upgrading the project.el package fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that upgrading the `project.el` package to 0.5.3 fixes the binding problem.

To do this I first had to fix the GNU TLS algorithm priority as described in this [Emacs Stack Exchange answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37904/how-do-i-work-out-what-the-problem-is-with-the-emacs-package-system). Once this was added I could successfully load the GNU ELPA package list and upgrade to the latest `project.el` package.

With the 0.5.3 version I can use `(require 'project)` or `use-package` to load project and get the key map bound correctly.