# Failed to download ‘melpa-stable’ archive. GnuTLS : Contacting host: 443

Tags: package-repositories, error-handling, gnutls, ssl

I am trying to install packages/modes from melpa on my emacs27.1, but I am unable to do so. If I run `M-x package-refresh-contents` , I get the following error :

```
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
gnutls.el: (err=[-50] The request is invalid.) boot: (:priority NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3 :hostname elpa.gnu.org :loglevel 0 :min-prime-bits nil :trustfiles (/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt) :crlfiles nil :keylist nil :verify-flags nil :verify-error nil :callbacks nil)
Failed to download ‘gnu’ archive.
gnutls.el: (err=[-50] The request is invalid.) boot: (:priority NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3 :hostname stable.melpa.org :loglevel 0 :min-prime-bits nil :trustfiles (/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt) :crlfiles nil :keylist nil :verify-flags nil :verify-error nil :callbacks nil)
Package refresh done
Failed to download ‘melpa-stable’ archive.
You can run the command ‘package-refresh-contents’ with M-x pa-r- RET
Failed to download ‘melpa-stable’ archive.
```

My emacs init file has the following commands corresponding to this function:

```
(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")
(package-initialize)
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

By tracing a little I thought the error might be due to GnuTLS and it could not connect to the internet. So I tried `M-x eww RET https://www.wikipedia.org/ RET`, it stops at `Contacting host: www.wikipedia.org:443` and does not load anything.

Prior to this, I was running on emacs25 (updated to 27.1 thinking this error would go away), and when I ran `M-x eww RET https://www.wikipedia.org/ RET` on emacs25, I would get

```
Contacting host: www.wikipedia.org:443
gnutls.el: (err=[-50] The request is invalid.) boot: (:priority NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3 :hostname www.wikipedia.org :loglevel 0 :min-prime-bits 256 :trustfiles (/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt) :crlfiles nil :keylist nil :verify-flags nil :verify-error nil :callbacks nil)
gnutls-negotiate: GnuTLS error: #<process www.wikipedia.org>, -50
```

Though I am running on Ubuntu 18.04LTS I tried the answer mentioned [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27202/how-do-i-install-gnutls-for-emacs-25-1-on-windows) hoping it would work, but unfortunately it did not. Please let me know if I need to add something more to my init file, or download some certificate or anything else.

Comment: You may want to try [disabling TLS 1.3](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62321/291); I realize that's for Emacs 26, but it is worth a try...though as the answer says, it's a workaround but not a good one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I removed TLS 1.3 from the init file and tried M-x eww and got the following error.

`error in process filter: eww-display-html: This function requires Emacs to be compiled with libxml2`.

However, `M-x package-refresh-contents` works and I was able to install jedi successfully and use it. Even though this is not a solution to make GnuTLS work, it made `package-refresh-contents` work, so I believe you can write your comment as an answer so that it will help those who face same problem in the future. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer but too long for a comment...

Among the various Emacs that I'm using, I use the default `emacs-nox` package from Ubuntu 18.04 (v25.2.2), and the default `emacs-nox` package from Ubuntu 21.04 (v27.1). I ​have the following for my package+use-package config. Connections to elpa/melpa, and https websites via `eww` are working fine for me. This is basically universal to all my Emacs configs.

If it wasn't for your errors with `eww` I'd have just blamed your issue on elpa being elpa...

Maybe the addition to `gnutls-trustfiles`
​will make a difference for you?

```lisp
(require 'package)
(when (>= emacs-major-version 27)
 ​(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
            ​'("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

;; Bootstrap 'use-package'
(eval-after-load 'gnutls
 ​'(add-to-list 'gnutls-trustfiles "/etc/ssl/cert.pem"))
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
 ​(package-refresh-contents)
 ​(package-install 'use-package))
(eval-when-compile
 ​(require 'use-package))
(require 'bind-key)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I could not find "/etc/ssl/cert.pem" on my system. So if you could tell me where I can find that, I will use it and let you know if your suggestion works (and also accept your answer as correct).